# delphi app with just a webbrowser dont start

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.3-rio, embedded-browser

i have rad studio 10.3 rio

in my new project i just put a single webbrowser component and app hanged on start and dont start in both emulator and mobile phone

[image]

when i remove the webbrowser and and add any other component like edit button and etc every thing is ok

the emulator is android 7.1 and mobile is Samsung A5 with android 6

is this a bug? is there any thing else i must do ?

**ps**:there is no code to paste,this is a simple project with just one TWebbrowser component.

Comment: Does it just hang on that screen forever?

Comment: PS - Activate your Windows!

Comment: Well spotted, @JerryDodge.

Comment: Do not activate your Windows. If you are using your windows licence for repairing stuff and have to keep re-installing it all the time Microsoft will stop allowing you to use your windows licence. In fact there is no legal way to use your Windows licence. There is nothing wrong at all with not registering your licence and Microsoft do not mind you not registering. There is an interesting article on this by Linus Tech Tips if anyone is interested. Google it

Comment: @JerryDodge yes,it hangs on that screen for ever.

Comment: @JerryDodge ,jamesc i need to reinstall windows every week on my test computer ,so its in trial period. thank you

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to try reinstall RAD Studio is better to change your rad studio version and check to install all hot fixes.

Comment: 10.3 is latest version.